# New MacBook with USB-C does not recognize an older DVD drive via USB to USB-C adapter

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, external-disk, optical-drive

I just got a new MacBook and a QGeeM adapter between USB and USB-C. Trying to connect an older Apple DVD drive that has the usual USB connector. The new MacBook doesn't recognize that a device has been connected.

Tried restarting MacBook, connecting QGeeM to different USB-C and the DVD drive to different USB ports of QGeeM. At some point a popup appeared that the external device needs power and should be connected to a USB port, which makes no sense because it is. Tried to chat with Apple, but they were extremely unhelpful and dropped the chat.

Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: There's no reason why macOS won't see an older USB device.  I'm using Catalina as we speak with an "old-ish" DVD-RW from Plextor and it's working just fine.  I suspect its that QGeeM adapter (never heard of that brand).  I use Anker for a majority of my USB needs (mostly because of their 18 month warranty)  See this [USB-C to USB-A adapter](https://amzn.to/2yTNGwt).

Comment: I'd try the old DVD drive in a friend's USB-equipped Mac. If it appears on the desktop, the QGeeM adapter is faulty. If the old drive doesn't appear, the drive or cable is faulty. Check your MacBook's USB-C socket by trying a USC-C drive connected directly to the MacBook. If the drive appears, the QGeeM adapter and/or cable is faulty.

Comment: Maybe worth checking https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202665 - Apple only support the SuperDrive on some Macs and via three specific adapters.  If it’s not the SuperDrive then could you please edit your post to say who made the drive?

Comment: This [Belkin adapter cable](https://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F2CU036/) is your best bet. After years of experience at my workplace, which has used hundreds of adapters on the past year alone, we've done quality testing on may brands as are found on Amazon and Ali Baba. Belkin and Anker are our go-to manufacturers. You may also have some luck with USBC>USBA adapters which are sometimes shipped with chrome books. We have a drawer of Dell or Samsung (I forget which) branded adapters of this sort.